# If a proxy is good then how to stick only to that proxy until gets banned and then move to another one, in scrapy-proxy-rotation?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Yesterday, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245976/getting-crawled-324-pages-at-133-pages-min-scraped-304-items-at-130-items-m/58249717?noredirect=1#comment102878831_58249717) and from the answer I figured out that I need to use proxies to scrape that site. So I implement [scrapy-rotation-proxy](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies) in that script.

**Here is the changed settings.py**

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH = '/my/path/proxies.txt'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

After implementing all of that, the scrapy still stops after scraping about 370+ pages. Since I am new in rotation-proxy, I want to know how to stick only to one proxy/ip(in case if that's good),until that gets banned,before rotating to another proxy/ip in proxies.txt file. Because I noticed that in case if a proxy is good, the required data gets scraped as shown below

```
2019-10-06 12:50:11 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://197.254.16.30:8080> is DEAD
2019-10-06 12:50:11 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.gulahmedshop.com/khadi-net-3-pc-outfit-glamour-19-48> with another proxy (failed 3 times, max retries: 5)
2019-10-06 12:50:12 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://181.30.95.162:33078> is GOOD
2019-10-06 12:50:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.gulahmedshop.com/gls-18-143> (referer: https://www.gulahmedshop.com/women?cat=399&price=-3000)
2019-10-06 12:50:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.gulahmedshop.com/gls-18-143>
{'Image Url': u'https://d224nth7ac0evy.cloudfront.net/catalog/product/cache/1e8ef93b9b4867ab9f3538dde2cb3b8a/g/l/gls-18-143_1_.jpg', 'Price': u'PKR 2,058', 'Category Name': u'and above', 'Product Title': u'GLS-18-143', 'Prouct page': 'https://www.gulahmedshop.com/gls-18-143'}
2019-10-06 12:50:12 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://171.239.46.185:8080> is DEAD
2019-10-06 12:50:12 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.gulahmedshop.com/gls-18-230> with another proxy (failed 2 times, max retries: 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need persistent sessions, you don’t want to do that.

You want requests to be spread across your different proxies, so that the amount of requests per minute of each proxy is as low as possible, making it less likely that they are throttled.

If you are using free proxies, what you need is either more free proxies, switching to paid proxies or, even better, a single [smart proxy](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera).

It would also bee a good idea to figure out why you are getting banned in the first place, but that can be hard to do.